# Error: Page contains property "query-input" which is not part of the schema

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I get this error from the [Google RichSnippets testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets):

> Error: Page contains property "query-input" which is not part of the schema.

But where did I make a mistake?

**HTML**:

```html
<div id="dkAjaxSearch">
<input id="ajaxSearch" type="text" value="" name="search_term" itemprop="query-input">
Press Enter to search
</div>
```

**JSON-LD**:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
   "@context": "http://schema.org",
   "@type": "WebSite",
   "url": "https://domain.com/",
   "potentialAction": {
     "@type": "SearchAction",
     "target": "http://domain.com/search/{search_term_string}",
     "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
   }
}
</script>
```

**Documentation**: [An improved search box within the search results](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html)

Answer (score 3):

It’s explained in the [documentation about Actions](http://schema.org/docs/actions.html):

> Additional information is often required from a user or client in order to formulate a complete request. To facilitate this process we need the ability to describe within a potential action how to construct these inputs. Since we need this capability for filling in any property of an Action, we introduce a notion of property annotations using a hypen ("-") delimiter. For example, by specifying a "location-input" property on a potential action we are indicating that "location" is a supported input for completing the action.

But as this property does not exist (i.e., it’s not defined in the property table on [`SearchAction`](http://schema.org/SearchAction)), validators report it as an error.

This issue already gets discussed on Schema.org’s GitHub: [SearchAction example uses "query-input" property that is not defined](https://github.com/rvguha/schemaorg/issues/155)

So you did not do something wrong. Unless Schema.org decides that Actions should be handled in a different way, validators should probably update and allow `-input` and `-output` suffixes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `query-input` value (in your case `search_term_string`) must match the input field name.

in your case:

```
<input id="ajaxSearch" type="text" value="" name="search_term" itemprop="query-input">
```

must be:

```
<input id="ajaxSearch" type="text" value="" name="search_term_string" itemprop="query-input">
```

Comment: Do you have this anywhere documented?

Comment: @Sekai https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/09/improved-sitelinks-search-box.html see update

Comment: I think they only meant that what's in Target should be in query-input. They didn't mention the HTML though.
I checked on some sites like Moz & Pinterest, they're not modifying their html input name.

Comment: This is not clear in any docs, Google or Schema. The use of the terminology "input" is too loose and is causing confusion. It could be generalized by an implementor to mean the `input` (data) that crawlers need, the `input` within the schema markup or the actual `input` element being targeted. 

Also nothing specifically describes the input element's name attribute. This seems like a critical piece of info.  
 Where can we read that to confirm it.